# Calculate divergence of vector in curvilinear coordinates using the metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, vector-fields

In a curved $(3+1)$ dimensional spacetime with metric components $g_{\mu \nu}$, the covariant derivative of a $4$ vector $\mathbf V = (V^0, \vec V)$ is given by 
$$\nabla_\mu~ V^\mu = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_\mu (\sqrt{-g}~V^\mu).$$

I expect that this relation can also be used to derive the expression for divergence of the $3$ vector $\vec V$ in a flat spatial hypersurface in a curvilinear coordinate system, eg. the cylindrical polar coordinates $(r,\phi,z)$. We will then need to replace the $\sqrt{-g}~$ by $\sqrt g~$ as the metric of the spatial hypersurface has a positive determinant. This will then give
$$\vec \nabla \cdot \vec V = \nabla_i V^i = \frac{1}{r}\partial_r(r~V^r) + \partial_\phi V^\phi + \partial_zV^z.$$

However, the actual expression for the divergence of a $3$ vector in cylindrical polar coordinates is
$$\vec \nabla \cdot \vec V = \frac{1}{r}\partial_r(r~V^r) + \frac{1}{r}\partial_\phi V^\phi + \partial_zV^z.$$
Can you please point out and explain where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both identities are correct. The point is that they refer to different bases. The former uses the decomposition,
$$\vec{V} = V^r \partial_r + V^\theta \partial_\theta + V^z \partial_z\:,$$
the latter uses the decomposition,
$$\vec{V} = V'^r \vec{e}_r + V'^\theta \vec{e}_\theta + V'^z \vec{e}_z\:,$$
where $\vec{e}_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{ii}}} \partial_{x^i}$ are unit vectors, so that  $V'^i = \sqrt{g_{ii}} V^i$ (there is *no* sum over the repeated index $i$).

Comment: For the OP, this is a common hangup when graduating from vector calculus to differential geometry (as it is used in general relativity).  Vector calculus almost always is taught using unit vectors for a basis, but the natural basis vectors corresponding to a set of coordinates are typically not unit.

Comment: Vector calculus is a silly thing to teach, since you have to unlearn most of it...

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. So, in the first case, $\partial_{x_i}$ are the coordinate basis vectors. But I do not realise how one shall know that the unit vectors in the second basis will be given by $\vec e_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{ii}}} \partial_{x_i}$.

Comment: One has $g\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{ii}}}\partial_i, \frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{ii}}}\partial_i\right)= \frac{1}{g_{ii}}g(\partial_i,\partial_i)= \frac{1}{g_{ii}} g_{ii}=1$. Therefore $\frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{ii}}}\partial_i$ is a unit vector, tangent to the coordinate $x^i$. Consequently, if $i=r$ it coincides with $\hat{r}= \vec{e}_r$, if $i=\theta$ it coincides with $\hat{\theta}= \vec{e}_\theta$, if $i=z$ it coincides with $\hat{\theta}= \vec{e}_z$.

Comment: Sorry, I used spherical coordinates but your referred to cylindrical ones, in my answer $\phi$ should be replaced for $z$. I corrected it.

Comment: Could you please have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4092768/333392 this question of mine. I think my doubt is almost the same what you have answered here. I think the answer to the first question of mine there is that, that’s because the transformation is orthogonal. For the second question there I think the answer is just that they are writing the transformation matrix keeping in mind the basis vector are unit length. I think I am correct but just wanted some expert to confirm my whether what I am saying above is correct or not. Would be really great if you can confirm so